# Ubuntu doesn't display fonts properly on some sites like Facebook

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, fonts

I had the same issue on OpenSUSE. ms fonts is installed. Tried with the following 2 browsers:

- Firefox
- Chrome

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing but the language setting in facebook was set to something like Urdu (I don't know how) which caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on 16.04 ? If yes, give this command a try

```
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

There will be an EULA for which you should give " yes ".

Comment: I've already installed that, I'm afraid.

Comment: What's that you have in home /.fonts folder ?

Comment: Strange, I don't even have a ~/.fonts folder.

Comment: Try this : After installing the font package you will need to update the shared font directories with the following command in a terminal shell.

sudo fc-cache -f -v

Comment: Or : Method 2) Create a directory into your home folder, and name it ".fonts". In this folder you can copy all fonts from Windows (C:\WINDOWS\Fonts).